# Dehalogenation of vicinal dihalides

Tags: organic-chemistry, transition-metals, halides, reactivity, hydrocarbons

Why, among different metals, only zinc is favourable for the dehalogenation of vicinal dihalides?

Comment: Magnesium + ether will also reduce a vicinal dihalide to an alkene.

Comment: I guess, mostly for safety and simplicity reasons. Magnesium tends to react vigorously with alkylhalogenides and aluminium forms oxide coating. Let's not even talk about such cases as sodium.

Answer (score 7):

Zinc is used effectively in the dehalogention of vicinal dihalides because a carbon zinc complex is formed in the mechanism which is probably more stable. This reaction is also known as [Simmon' Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simmons%E2%80%93Smith_reaction) reaction.

[image]

> The stability and usefulness of the Simmons-Smith reagent (zinc metal)
> may be attributed in part to the **higher covalency of the carbon-zinc
> bond together with solvation and internal coordination of the zinc** (which makes the zinc complex stable). ([Source](http://chem.libretexts.org/Core/Organic_Chemistry/Alkyl_Halides/Reactivity_of_Alkyl_Halides/Alkyl_Halide_Reactions/Reactions_of_Dihalides))
>
> Reduction of vicinal dihalides by zinc metal proceeds by way of
> oxidative insertion of Zn(0) into a C-X bond, producing an organozinc
> species (stable) which undergoes dehalogenation:
>
> [image]
>
> ([source](http://tminehan.com/spring333pdfs/Lecture13org.pdf))

Comment: The Simmons-Smith reaction is the dehalogenation of a **geminal** dihalide, and thus shouldn’t be the main point of interest here.