# Dehalogenation of vicinal dihalo alkanes

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides, elimination

Which mechanism will the following reaction follow?

[image]

Will it follow E2 mechanism?
If yes, then how would 2,3-dibromobutane undergo this reaction?

Does it form both cis and trans butene or is the product butyne?

[Here is a link to a website that has mentioned it is E2 mechanism but has low stereospecificity.](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Alkyl_Halides/Reactivity_of_Alkyl_Halides/Alkyl_Halide_Reactions/Reactions_of_Dihalides#:%7E:text=The%20reaction%20to%20the%20right,a%20lower%20degree%20of%20stereospecificity.&text=This%20elimination%20generates%20the%20same,each%20of%20the%20bromo%2Dalkenes.)  So does Zn act as the base donating the electrons? If this happens then why isn't hydrogen leaving the substrate resulting in dehydrohalogenation and formation of alkyne? Why are two halogens leaving the substrate to give an alkene instead of alkyne

Comment: A repost of a closed question will be closed as well. The proper way is to address the closure reason by editing of the original question and asking to reopen it.

Comment: Now it depends on reagents you use. You need to provide a point where you feel yourself to be unsatisfied. Now there are multiple ways using a **bulky and a strong base, using NaI acetone, Using Alcoholic KOH**. So you need to specify the reagents also as different reagents follow different mechanisms

Comment: I had provided a whole explanation on what I was unsatisfied.
I even requested that an elaborate question was necessary for the contributors to understand what doubt I had.

Comment: It was taken down stating that it was too broad of a question and needed specific focus. I am not happy with the moderators for the first time. They seem to be focusing more on the 'how to post a question' than explaining a doubt. I understand serious offenses can be taken down, I don't understand why moderators cannot just suggest edits if they feel the question is so easily explainable in lesser magnitude of words. @Poutnik

Comment: @Anonymous The reagent was Zn
Can you just tell me what reaction mechanism it follows? I'll try to continue it myself from there. My teacher had taken it as an example for E2 but i doubt it.

Comment: Well, moderators of any moderated sites are not very happy with users posting questions before  getting familiar with the site policy. It seems to me you have confused too broad with too deep, so instead of narrowing it,  you have ended with shallowing it. Site policies are for advantage of the whole SE community, which aims for the high-quality of answers AND questions. Without it, it would be like dozens of other topical sites ,mostly forums, with lots of garbage.

Comment: BTW, they were not necessarily moderators, they could be as well senior users with Q close voting privilege. 5 such votes, with chosen reason, is enough for the Q to be closed.

Comment: @Desai If there is a metal than the most common use of metal is to give electrons. Now it depends on you how and where you feel that your substance should give electrons(it is on you how judiciously you use the electrons)

Comment: Also please add the reagent in this question so that other community members can help you too

Comment: I found an article on ChemLibreTexts which states that the reaction proceeds by E2 mechanism but has low stereospecificity.

Comment: @Desai provide a link to that in your question and also provide your point of concern in that

Comment: related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/57928/102629