# Can dehalogenation reaction occur through E2 mechanism?

Tags: organic-chemistry, elimination

I have seen examples of dehydrohalogenation reaction that occur through E2 mechanism but never came across dehalogenation reaction that occur through E2 mechanism (for example, dehalogenation of 1,2-chloropropane).

Why is that all dehalogenation reaction occur through E1 reaction, if not can someone give a counterexample for it?

Comment: Isn't dehydrohalogenation same as dehalogenation?

Comment: @NisargBhavsar I thought dehalogenation was removal of 2 halogen atoms

Comment: How can 2 halogens be eliminated simultaneously? Is an halogen acidic enough to get this done?

Comment: @NisargBhavsar Reaction of 1,2-chloropropane with Zn dust

Comment: That's via a radical mechanism and not E1 or E2.

Comment: @NisargBhavsar I was taught that $2^{°}$Cl was removed from 1,2-chloropropane to form $ZnCl^-$ and carbocation.

Comment: You are suggesting a near-impossible mechanism. See this question's answer for the mechanism - https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57928/dehalogenation-of-vicinal-dihalides (Ignore the first few lines in the answer about Simmons-Smith reaction)

Comment: Please note that in 'E1' and 'E2' there is no need to use MathJax: the E should be upright and the number is not subscripted. If you want to use MathJax (again, not necessary) then you should use `$\mathrm{E1}$` and `$\mathrm{E2}$`. There is also no need to enclose parentheses with math mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dehalogenation of vicinal dihalides can occur through the E2 mechanism. After some digging, I found [this article from 1955](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja01624a026). The full text is behind a paywall for me, so I cannot cite the specific rate constants, but the general findings are that *trans*-1,2-dihalocylohexanes undergo iodide-mediated dehalogenation more rapidly than the *cis*-stereoisomer.

[image]

These findings suggest the *anti* conformation is necessary, which supports the E2 mechanism.

[image]

[This answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/57928/dehalogenation-of-vicinal-dihalides/58840#58840) suggests that the final step of the reductive dehalogenation of vicinal dihalides by zinc dust is E2-like.